# custom cutting lumber or custom cut lumber or custom lumber cutting

Tags: differences, adjectives

I know custom picking strawberry, to a certain extent, as I think ,is right. I have confirmed it in google. But here comes the problem: when I try to apply the same structure to "customers can cut the lumber the way the want it to be", it goes wrong. Just tracing the structure above, I would say custom cutting lumber, but I found it to be like"custom cut lumber" and "custom lumber cutting".Which is right?
so I am badly confused. I think this is a worthy question to be discussed.

Comment: I think you are confusing *custom VERBed* with *customer VERBed*. The former designates something *VERBed* **for** an individual customer; the latter (which, frankly, I do not recall encountering) would designate something *VERBed* **by** an individual customer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any results for *"custom picking strawberry"* in Google, so I don't see why you think it's acceptable English. In the U.S., places where you pick the strawberries yourself generally use the words *"pick your own strawberries"*.

The past participle of *"cut"* is *"cut"*. So we have the correspondence:

> *custom picked strawberries* →  *custom cut lumber*,
>   *custom strawberry picking* → *custom lumber cutting*.

If you want to talk about the process of cutting lumber to a customer-specified size, it's *"custom lumber cutting"*. If you want to talk about the results (in other words, about the lumber after it's been cut), it's *"custom cut lumber"*.

However, for both these terms, what is implied is that the lumber is cut to the customer's specifications, but not necessarily that the customer cuts it himself.

Comment: hey! I don't think cut there in that phrase is past tense.Because I think it's not a sentence but a phrase instead. So it can only be non-finite verb. And in the phrase, there are one subject and one object.Let's take custom cut lumber for an example. To custom, customers are the one who cut the lumber, so cut should use passive voice.To lumber, lumber are cut. So cut should use active voice.So I am still confused with it.

Comment: hey! I don't think cut there in that phrase is past tense.Because I think it's not a sentence but a phrase instead. So it can only be non-finite verb. And in the phrase, there are one subject and one object.Let's take custom cut lumber for an example. To custom, customers are the one who cut the lumber, so cut should use passive voice.To lumber, lumber are cut. So cut should use active voice.So I am still confused with it.

Comment: There's no rule that verbs used in phrases like this can't be past participles (which cut is here; not past tense; I've fixed my answer). Is the phrase *freshly caught fish* or *freshly catch fish*; *custom built house* or *custom build house*?